# Sale Quotation Line's Quantity (product_uom_qty) is not triggering onchange

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

In Sale Quotation Line, there is a field Quantity (product_uom_qty).
I want to customize something in its onchange event, but it does not seem to be triggering it when I change its value.

This is what I tried:

```
class sale_order_line_inherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    @api.onchange('product_uom', 'product_uom_qty')
    def product_uom_change(self):
        print(res)
        print(self.price_unit)
        res = super(sale_order_line_inherit, self).product_uom_change()
        print(res)
        print(self.price_unit)
```

Nothing gets printed at all.
I already included 'sale' in manifest as well.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to consider,

- How to change quantity from the frond end or script?
- Can you verify field name on the list/form view?
- Put print statement on the Odoo core `sale` module
- If still not working, put error code on the file and upgrade the module to identify file execute at all or not.

I don't have any issue in your code. This is alternative of your code.

```
@api.onchange('product_uom', 'product_uom_qty')
def product_uom_change(self):
    print(self.price_unit)
    super().product_uom_change()
    print(self.price_unit)
```